# how to get command prompt to open in userprofile

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-3.0

lam using windows 8. At first when l was opening command prompt it was using **C:\Users\Software Developer>** (Software Developer is my computer name) and l could easily access my desktop using **C:\Users\Software Developer>cd.. desktop**

l dont know what happened, now the command prompt by default is on **c:\windows\systems32>** if you enter **dir** it shows all the files on systems32.

l want to get it back to  **C:\Users\Software Developer>** so that l can access my desktop easily, and l know it has something to do with the Environment variables path/settings. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

l finally figured it out. There are two types of command prompt in windows 8, the elevated command prompt - which opens with the **c:\windows\systems32>** and the normal command prompt **which opens with c:\users\computer name>**

And can be both accessed using keyboard shortcut **(windows button + x )**